# ADS Wilkinson Power Divider

Tags: rf, microstrip, power-divider

I finished the schematic for my 2.4GHz microstrip Wilkinson power divider. I am moving to the layout and trying to do the EM simulation, but I cannot figure out how to put a lumped element in the layout design. This is the error I am getting:

[image]

If anyone could help me put lumped elements into the EM simulation that would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have EM model of resistor you cannot simulate it. Change the **partition rule to circuit** and run meshing and EM simulation. After that, create a component of this layout and place this as component this in a new schematic. The component looks like layout with pins at port ends and resistor. Now add the resistor in schematic and simulate S- Parameters.

Don't forget to place pins at the location you are placing resistor. They shouldn't be wrt to GND!
Check out this example image I have cropped out from one of my design
[image: Observe pins 1,3,4]

Pins 1 is wrt gnd which acts as Port 1 where as I place a passive component between port 3 and 4.

Check out this link for procedure to converting layout to component and simulating it.
[This is example of microstrip filter.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oz1qsJD64Cs)